# assigning TODO status to specific list items (not headings)

Tags: org-mode

What would be a way to achieve the following:

```
* interface A
** sample files
1 file "alpha"
2 file "beta"
    TODO fix missing tag
3 file "gamma"
```

E.g. I am trying to associate a `TODO` action with a specific list item as opposed to a heading. But it seems that only headings can be marked as `TODO` in org-mode. Should I use a checkbox instead given that it's [suggested](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) that they really are lightweight TODOs?

Comment: I think your post answers its own question: no TODOs for plain list items, but checkboxes instead.